# Equivalent of 'clear' command when using tail -f

Tags: macos, terminal.app, tail

I am using the `tail -f` command to follow an error log, and I often want to "clear" the terminal, much in the same way that the `clear` unix command moves everything above the top of the window. Is there something like this when using tail?

At the moment I just hit return a bunch of times which works okay, but gets rather annoying, especially when I have a tall window.

I am on mac os 10.6.8.

Comment: Can't you just go `"View" > "Clear Scrollback"` or press `⌘K`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`View` > `Clear Scrollback` or press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: And `Alt+F8` (right click, `Reset`) for Cygwin

Comment: `Ctrl+L` for Linux and IntelliJ/PhpStorm/etc

Answer (score 2):

There isn't.  Tail is reading a file, not your input.  You could get the source for tail and modify it to behave the way you want, but there's no built in way to do this.

Comment: You are right that there is not way **tail** can do this.